# How to change the background color of Selected Tab in TabLayout in android jetpack compose and then change it to other color after it's de-selected?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

So, I have three Tabs (Basic,Medium,Hard) in my TabLayout. The Basic Screen is the default screen which gets displayed first. I want a diffrent background color for it as it's selected and when i select one of the other two tabs, the selected color of **Basic** will go away and background color of one of the Tabs that is selected should be changed to indicate this Tab is selected.

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun TableLayout(navController: NavController) {
    var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    val tabs = listOf("Basic", "Medium", "Hard")

    Column(modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp).height(140.dp)
        .background(Color(153, 50, 204))
        .padding(top = 8.dp,)) {
        tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                text = { Text(title, color = Color.White, textAlign = TextAlign.Start) },
                selected = tabIndex == index,
                onClick = {
                    tabIndex = index
                    when (index) {
                        0 -> navController.navigate(Destinations.Basic)
                        1 -> navController.navigate(Destinations.Medium)
                        2 -> navController.navigate(Destinations.Hard)
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modifier in your Tab to change the background colour:

```
Tab(text = { Text(title, color = Color.White, textAlign = TextAlign.Start) },
      selected = tabIndex == index,
      onClick = { tabIndex = index /* ... */ },
      modifier = Modifier.background(if (tabIndex == index) Color.Red else Color.Blue))
```

EDIT full layout:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    TabRow(selectedTabIndex = tabIndex) {
        tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(text = { Text(title) },
                selected = tabIndex == index,
                onClick = { tabIndex = index },
                modifier = Modifier.background(if (tabIndex == index) Color.Red else Color.Blue)
            )
        }
    }
    when (tabIndex) {
        0 -> BasicScreen()
        1 -> MediumScreen()
        2 -> HardScreen()
    }
}
```

Edit 2 - entire TableLayout:

```
@Composable
fun TableLayout() {
    var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

val tabs = listOf("Basic", "Medium", "Hard")

Column(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(140.dp)
    .background(Color(153, 50, 204))
    .padding(top = 8.dp,)) {
    TabRow(selectedTabIndex = tabIndex) {
        tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                text = { Text(title, color = Color.White, textAlign = TextAlign.Start) },
                selected = tabIndex == index,
                onClick = { tabIndex = index },
            )
        }
    }
    when (tabIndex) {
        0 -> BasicScreen()
        1 -> MediumScreen()
        2 -> HardScreen()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I click on **Medium** Tab or **Hard** Tab, those Screens are opened but the Color Red which was associated with **Basic** Tab remains there only even if one of the other two tabs have been selected.

Comment: I think it's because you're using the navController and navigating away so the selectedTab is always at 0. I edited my code to include the full layout

Comment: Now it's getting how I want but the Screens are not changing they remain on Basicscreen only, no matter which Tab I select. P.S :- This TabLayout has been used in all the screens . I will put the entire BasicScreen code in edit

Comment: you should edit the question with the extra code not the answer :)

Comment: `0 -> BasicScreen()
        1 -> MediumScreen()
        2 -> HardScreen()`This is giving an error. @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function @Eliza

Comment: Do you have it perhaps in the TabRow block? It should be inside the Column but outside of the TabRow

Comment: I did as you said. could you simply edit the  entire TableLayout so I can get an idea what actually I am missing from what you telling me to do? Thank you

Comment: Check the new edit

Comment: Nope it doesn't , now it gives error on clicking Card itself , even before showing the TabLayout screen

Comment: Well, whats's the error? The exact code works for me, so the error comes from the rest of your compose hierarchy.

Comment: It basicallly crashes and gives following error in Logcat. Added in the edit

Comment: Shall I send you my github link of this project? I tried to edit and put the logcat message, it's saying you are exceeding the limit of characters .

Comment: sure although I'm not sure I can have a look at it this week I'm afraid

Comment: https://github.com/klaus19/BasicComposeApp Thank you.